# Change MUI Paper properties using a variable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I set properties of MUI's paper using a variable? I tried this but it does not work, how can I fix this?

```
   var bs = 1;
    <Paper
        sx={{
        width: '-moz-fit-content',
        width: 'fit-content',
        minWidth: 70,
        boxShadow: {bs}, //<====== here
        borderRadius: 0,
        backgroundColor:"red",
            }}>
                        </Paper>
```

Comment: Because that's using [object shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015), equivalent to `boxShadow: { bs: 1 }`. You need to pay attention to when you're in a JSX context, and `{}` are needed for interpolating JavaScript expressions, and when you're not.

Comment: Ok, How do i fix it?

Comment: Remove the braces? Right there you're just in a regular JavaScript object.

Comment: How ludicrous of me! That worked thanks.